# App not staying in landscape when rotated on tablet... Android 4.0

Tags: android, sdk, webview, orientation

I know this gets asked a lot here. I've been looking at hundreds of pages on Google but can't pinpoint why my app won't stay in landscape mode:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="-------------"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"   >
    <activity android:name="---------Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
  android:id="@+id/mainWebView">
 </WebView>
```

It's just an app with one WebView...

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the activity in the `AndroidManifest`. For example:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set android:screenOrientation for each activity. Instead you're doing it on the application.
Also, screenOrientation and configChanges does nothing for layout xml files.